# Incompatible pointer types assigning NSDictionary to parameter of type NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am trying to convert a dictionary to an array in objective-c. I am getting this warning on line three. 'incompatible pointer types assigning nsdictionary to parameter of type nsarray'. Is there any way to convert that dictionary to an array without getting that warning?

```
// in DataSource.h

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *bars;

// in MasterViewController.m

       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


    NSDictionary *JSONDict = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
    _dataSource.recievedJSON = JSONDict;
    _dataSource.bars = [NSArray arrayWithArray:JSONDict];

    self.title = @"Bars";
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // display alert if error downlading data
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Without knowing how you're declaring `bars` one can only answer "yes", without giving you any further advice.

Comment: An NSDictionary is not an NSArray, so why would you try to pass it as the argument to `arrayWithArray:`? That's nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying:

```
[NSArray arrayWithArray:JSONDict]
```

But `JSONDict` is an NSDictionary, while `arrayWithArray:` expects an NSArray. So why are you doing that?

You need to think about how you want to turn this dictionary into an array — if that's your goal — and then *you* need to do that. You need to understand the structure of the dictionary and think about what sort of "array" this could possibly be turned into.

Comment: But why you want to turn a dictionary into an array at all is completely mystifying, so I can't say more than that. Why don't you just store it as what it is - a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert a NSDictionary(key-value pair) to NSArray but if you want to get array of keys and values of a dictionary, so can try this.

```
NSDictionary* dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object1",@"key1",@"object2",@"key2",@"object3",@"key3", nil];
NSArray* arrKeys = dic.allKeys;
NSArray* arrValues = dic.allValues;
```